# Returning all numbers in regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to find all the hard coded IDs that have been put in the application.  I've created a console app that I'm trying to find all the IDs.  I'm running into several issues.

I have a lot of different formats that I'm trying to find but I figure I'll do 1 at a time for now:

For example I have the following:

```
if ((Id != "28" && Id != "29" && Id != "9" && Id != "123" && Id != "904"))
```

This only returns "9"

```
Match match = Regex.Match(line, "Id != \"[0-9]\"",  RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

if (match.Success) {
    string key = match.Groups[0].Value;
    Console.WriteLine(key);
}
```

I would like to know how I can return every number found in my example above.  I would like to return:

- 28
- 29
- 9
- 123
- 904

Comment: you're overthinking it.  Just grab anything that matches one more numbers - `[0-9]+`

Comment: @Jonesopolis - I'm not great with RegEx - so "overthinking it" is giving me too much credit.  Thanks, that was the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to match one or more digit, and either call `Matches` to get *all* matches, or call next match to continue the search:

```
Match match = Regex.Match(line, "Id != \"([0-9]+)\"",  RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

while (match.Success) {
    string key = match.Groups[1].Value;
    Console.WriteLine(key);
    match = match.NextMatch();
}
```

The changes from your code are as follows:

- Replaced `[0-9]` with `([0-9]+)`
- Switched to using `Groups[1]` from `Groups[0]` to ignore the irrelevant parts
- Added a loop and a call to `NextMatch()`.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/Rtajo3)

Answer (score 1):

you should call `.Matches`

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(line, "Id != \"([0-9]+)\"",  RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

foreach(Match match in matches)
    string key = match.Groups[1].Value;
    Console.WriteLine(key);
}
```

Comment: @wdosanjos you are right. I didn't look into the regex part. Edited and thx

Comment: The matches collection works on the whole text file.  Thanks!